# Multi login using PHP/MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, session

I need to do a multi userlogin, so the admin will be logged into admin.php and the clerk will be redirected into clerk.php.

But I am having a issue. I have  coded it so far and it lets me redirect clerk to clerk.php. But my admin login just returns me back to the index.php. Github if you want a better idea. https://github.com/markRichie/MSS

This is my code below.

Functions.php:

```
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if($row["Role"] == "admin")
        {
           $_SESSION['User'] = $row["username"];
           $_Session['Role'] = $row["Role"];
           header('Location: admin.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['User'] = $row["username"];
            $_Session['Role'] = $row["Role"];
            header('Location: clerk.php');
        }
    }

    }
    else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Admin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['Role']))
{
  if($_SESSION['Role'] != 'admin')
  {
    header('Location: clerk.php');
  }
}
else
{
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

And my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `multilogin` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Role` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: This could mean that the query is returning 0 result, can you add your MySQL query?

Comment: I don't see where the OP received an "Undefined variable" notice or any notice, so I am not sure why this question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, no clue why they closed my thread. It had nothing to do with the similar thread...

Comment: @NathanDeLima It has *everything* to do with it. Undefined, plain and simple. Whoever voted to reopen, should not have. If it gets reopened, I will flag for moderation, and/or post on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not:

```
$_Session['Role'] = $row["Role"];
```

But rather:

```
$_SESSION['Role'] = $row["Role"];
```

You misspelled `$_SESSION` in two places in file `Functions.php`.

**Code to handle multiple roles:**

You need to code for each role a separate file such as `admin.php`, `clerk,php`, `doctor.php`, `patient.php`, etc. and then:

*Functions.php:*

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['User'] = $row['username'];
    $role = $row['role'];
    $_SESSION['Role'] = $role;
    // $role is 'admin' or 'clerk' or 'doctor' or 'patient' etc.
    header("Location: $role.php");
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Appreciate it. I can't believe I missed that. Adding onto one more question. If I were to add more multi-users.  E.g Doctors, patients and so forth. What would I have to change or where would I start? I assume in functions.php I need to add another IF? Thank you again.

Comment: I've updated my answer on how I would probably handle multiple roles.

Comment: Somebody downvoted me -- not sure why. Feel free to accept this as the valid answer.

Comment: Thanls bro. I upvoted your stuff. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, but somebody offset your upvote with a downvote. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). No pressure.